# Xcode 15 compile error: Import of C++ module 'zlib' appears within extern "C" language linkage specification

Tags: c++, ios, c, zlib, xcode15

I am trying to compile an existing project with Xcode 15 RC, the project uses some dependencies that internally use `zlib`.

`zlib.h` is included using

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifndef _ZLIB_H
#include "zlib.h"
#endif
...
```

I get this error: `Import of C++ module 'zlib' appears within extern "C" language linkage specification`

Everything was working fine on Xcode 14. Is `zlib` a c++ library now?

I can move the includes out of the `extern "C"` scope, but my I have POD dependencies failing and I don't have control over them, I can try using `cocoapods-patch` but I wonder if there is an easier way to solve this problem.

Comment: Side note:  `#ifndef _ZLIB_H` you shouldn't need to do this.  First, macros with leading underscores are reserved.  Second, doesn't the `zlib.h` file already have `#include` guards?

Comment: like I said it is not my code, it is in dependencies I am using

Comment: Move the `#include "zlib.h"` out of the `extern "C"` works for me, I'm looking for a flag to disable this instead but not yet found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`extern "C" {` is a C++ feature that is invalid in C and further code in that block is expected to be C.

zlib.h has own `extern "C" {`, and when you include zlib.h in `extern "C" {` you get nested `extern "C" {` and the compiler warns you about that: C++ code is met where C code is expected.

Don't include zlib.h in `extern "C" {` block, move the last after all inclusions.

Comment: `extern "C"` is being used only in C++ 

```#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif``` this is somehow specific to the compiler shipped with xcode 15

Comment: The first `extern "C"` does not undefine `__cplusplus`, you get `extern "C"` nested in `extern "C"`. They just improved or extended compiler diagnostics. You should note place `#include` inside `extern "C"`.

Comment: That can't be the reason it fails. Nested `extern "C"` specifications are allowed.
 "Linkage specifications nest. When linkage specifications nest, the innermost one determines the language linkage." [9.11.5]

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all that, as well as the `#ifdef` for the closing brace undoubtedly in your `...`. Replace it with simply:

```cpp
#include "zlib.h"
```

That's it. zlib.h already *has* the include guard and `extern "C"`.

Answer (score -1):

You can hide the error if you uncheck:

```
Xcode > Build Settings > Apple Clang Module Verifier - Options > Enable Module Verifier
```